# Hot code replace / hotswap in Eclipse while remote debugging

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, remote-debugging

We are developing an Eclipse RCP application. Because of this, the usual local development workflow is to also use Eclipse as an IDE and compile, run, debug from the Eclipse IDE.

I'd like to use another IDE (namely IntelliJ IDEA) to edit and debug code.

I can sort of accept that code still has to be compiled using Eclipse and I don't mind having Eclipse open on the side and switching to it every now and then.

I've managed to remote debug the running RCP application. The crux is to add the proper VM args to the launch configuration

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,suspend=y,address=localhost:37135
```

This works fine for debugging, but I'd also like to have hot code replacement / hotswapping.

I can also start the RCP application directly from the command line by copying the command given in the launch configuration ("Show command Line").

The problem is that it seems that Eclipse only does hotswapping when you run the product with "Debug" and not "Run". But when you do *that*, VM args like the above are *automatically* added, with a random port number. Eclipse's debugger then is directly attached to that port, making it impossible to attach my remote debugger.

It seems that when running the product with "Debug", something additional happens that facilitates hotswapping.

How can I have "remote" debugging (in a different IDE) and still build and hotswap with Eclipse?

Comment: I doubt that this is possible. HotSwap is part of debugging, not a separate thing ([HotSwap is done via tha Java Debug Wire Protocol (JDWP)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/enhancements1.4.html)). Does IntelliJ even get the class loading right or did you put all plugins onto a classpath? Be aware that IntelliJ does not support the development of Eclipse RCP applications, so you are blind to some important things.

Comment: Setting breakpoints and stepping through code seems to work fine in IntelliJ.

Note that I'm not building with IntelliJ, so the code change that should be hotswapped might as well have been done in Eclipse. It's just that Eclipse's "Debug" launch somehow facilitates hotswapping, which does not happen when invoking with "Run".

And using "Debug" makes it difficult to attach a remote debugger.

Comment: It can happen that IntelliJ shows you the wrong class. HotSwap is done via the debug protocol and as far as I know, you cannot connect two IDEs (one for setting breakpoints and displaying current values and one for HotSwap) to the same Java VM instance.

Comment: Okay, thank you. But could I, in principle, build the class files (correct term?) with eclipse and hotswap them in with IntelliJ? Using, for instance, something like [HotswapAgent](http://hotswapagent.org/index.html)?

Comment: I guess that for HotSwap the compiled bytecode and not the source code will be transferred to the Java VM. Again, IntelliJ does not support the development of Eclipse RCP applications. You are not the first person wasting time trying to do this.

Comment: I know that :) I don't want to replace Eclipse, I'm just trying to better understand how Eclipse facilitates hotswapping.

Comment: @fuyang-liu As of today, IntelliJ does not support the development of Eclipse RCP applications. A bounty on this question does not change this fact.

Comment: @howlger Again, this question is not asking "I want a full solution to develop RCP applications exclusively in Eclipse", it is about hotswapping with remote debugging.

Comment: IntelliJ does not support the development of Eclipse RCP applications which also includes hotswapping with remote debugging. You can't even trust IntelliJ to display variable values at the right location, even if it works in almost all cases. Be aware that in contrast to using a flat classpath, in OSGi a class with the same qualified name can be loaded at runtime in different versions at the same time (explore the limitation of the tool you are using with such an example and you will see).